# His words transcend ‘time’ or ‘times’ - Which is right?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

> 1. His words transcend times, thoughts, ages and all boundaries.

In the above example, I am confused whether it should be *time* or *times*.
 Should it be the following?

> 2. His words transcend time, thoughts, ages and all boundaries

Please clear my confusion.
Thank you.

Comment: Read the definitions carefully here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time and https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/times It all depends on what you want to communicate.

Comment: here, the word times is for defining different eras. So, is it correct to use times instead of time?

Comment: They're both "correct", it depends what you want the sentence to mean. 2.4 2.4 also **times** *A portion of time in history or characterized by particular events or circumstances*. 2.5 *The conditions of life during a particular period*

Comment: I shouldn't have posted the second link, it only gives the verb meaning. Sorry. The different meanings are found in the first Oxford Dict. link.

Comment: I'd say that only 'transcend time' (and arguably 'thought') is/are idiomatic for the first two objects here. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transcend+times%2Ctranscend+time%2Ctranscend+thoughts%2Ctranscendthought&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctranscend%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctranscend%20thoughts%3B%2Cc0) seem to support this. 'Right' is not an exact synonym of 'grammatical'. // There is also an issue with incongruousness if just one noun is in singular form (albeit as a non-count usage).

Comment: If you keep *times*, I would suggest a slight modification to your sentence: *His words transcend all times, thoughts, ages, and boundaries.* The use of *transcend times* sounds awkward to me; if using a plural, I would preface it with *the* or *all*. Since you already use *all*, just change its location so it modifies each of the nouns.

Comment: Yes, transcend all times, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"His Words Transcend Times"

Here **"Times"** has **"era, period"** meaning. You might have heard the saying **"times change"** or **"how times have changed"**. Therefore it becomes a countable noun. There can be more than one era.

If you use it without "s" I would interpret it as just "time". Not as a period but simply time. As in "Commuting takes a lot of time".

Both are fine in my opinion but "times" makes that sentence kind of poetic. Like, his words transcend through the ages, different periods of history.

Comment: Thanks. It truly helps me. I also thought the same way, but having doubts earlier. it gets cleared now.

Comment: "X is [older than time itself](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22older+than+time+itself%22&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9ne-_h_jaAhXCY98KHbH7AwQQ_AUIECgB&biw=1316&bih=619)" usually encompasses every era, period known to man.